# Can't set AutoSize property to dynamically created TextBox C# VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, textbox, autosize

I am creating TextBoxes at runtime and need them to have fixed width. However, as I expect some large inputs from the user, it is supposed to be multiline, increasing its height accordingly.

I've been able to set all sorts of properties, except AutoSize, which I believe I have to, because my TextBoxes aren't behaving as I want them to. When I type a large input, they keep everything in only one line, and as it has fixed length, it doesn't show the entire text.

C# won't let me do textbox1.Autosize = True;

Here's what I have so far:

```
   TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox()
    {
        Name = i.ToString() + j.ToString() + "a",
        Text = "",
        Location = new System.Drawing.Point(xCoord + 2, yCoord + 10),
        TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
        Font = new Font("ArialNarrow", 10),
        Width = 30,
        Enabled = true,
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
        Multiline = true,
        WordWrap = true,
        TabIndex = tabIndex + 1
    };
```

How do I set the Autosize property to a dynamically created TextBox?

Or is there another way to accomplish what I'm trying to?

Comment: Are you referring to this property [TextBoxBase.AutoSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.autosize?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Apparently yes. Although I'm not sure what 'Base' means. I have a textbox and want it to have one line when only one line is sufficient to show all its contents; and to increase in height to display more than one line when needed.

Comment: AutoSize doesn't do what you think. Read the docs linked above.

Comment: Thank you. But what does do it?

Comment: It changes the size of the TextBox if you change the Font assigned. It doesn't change the height of the TextBox if you add text. And you don't need to set it to true because that's the default. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691092/why-doesnt-autosize-property-in-windows-form-textbox-appear-in-intellisense

Comment: Thanks again for your patience. My question sounded dumb, but what I actually asked is what does what I am trying to do. Not what does Autosize do. Because I did read the link. Sorry.

Comment: Are you sure to have read the link till the end? _f you want to change the size of the control as the user enters text, you can use a RichTextBox control and use its ContentsResized event to change its size._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code to make the expected textbox.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private const int EM_GETLINECOUNT = 0xba;
    [DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "SendMessageA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern int SendMessage(int hwnd, int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox[,] tb = new TextBox[10, 10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                var txt = new TextBox();
                tb[i, j] = txt;
                tb[i, j].Name = "t";
                tb[i, j].Multiline = true;
                tb[i, j].WordWrap = true;
                tb[i, j].TextChanged += Tb_TextChanged;
                Point p = new Point(120 * i, 100 * j);
                tb[i, j].Location = p;
                this.Controls.Add(tb[i,j]);
            }

        }            
    }

    private void Tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        var numberOfLines = SendMessage(textBox.Handle.ToInt32(), EM_GETLINECOUNT, 0, 0);
        textBox.Height = (textBox.Font.Height + 2) * numberOfLines;
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response and time invested friend. However that didn't solve my problem because at the time the user writes in the textbox its name is not "textbox1" anymore. I have to create a varying amount of textboxes, up to 121. That's why I'm naming them like 11,22,33 and so on. I have no idea how to assign an event handler to something which name can vary from 00 to 121.

Comment: I have updated my code, which create 100 dynamic textboxes. You can check if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did exactly what I needed!